# Python - count distinct rows from a dataframe

Tags: python, database, pandas, numpy, anaconda

I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
UserId, CurrentUserLocationId, RegisteredUserLocationId, RestorauntId
```

I wish to count the amount of unique appearances of the key `(UserId, CurrentUserLocationId, RegisteredUserLocationId)`

For example, if the pair `(1, 1, 1)` appears once, I wish to stop counting and include it in the final result. So each unique pair that appears I need to count it only once.

What I tried doing is to use `groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']).size()` however this counts all the records. The dataset I will be using the code on has billion records.

Is there a built-in way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Or to be more precise, what's the fastest way to do this sort of counting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataFrame.drop_duplicates()
DataFrame.count
```

If necessary duplicate the dataframe before dropping duplicates and when making the duplicate dataframe only call in the columns you want to be unique combinations.

Comment: How long will drop_duplicates take to execute on billion records?

Comment: Hard to say, the removal of duplicates should be fairly efficient (for an ordered set, when the value is the same as the previous remove) but anything that large... it's hard to say.